# How to apply gradient background to a circle div in html css

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div in HTML and apply a gradient background like in the picture:

[image: circle with gradient border]

I have tried some js-fiddle snippets but was unable to do some thing like this in the image it will be used in a pricing table for displaying latest discounts. The other alternate I have is to use the hard quote the image in my pricing table.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

I tried the above link and applied `border-radius:50%` but didn't got the desired result.

Comment: "some js-fiddle snippets" is not really specific. Show what you have tried by providing a minimal working example of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border images are not yet well supported, so I think you need to use two containers with one being styled with `background: linear-gradient()`:

https://jsfiddle.net/nsvn00px/

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
}
.circle__inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 46px; height: 46px;
  top: 2px; left: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

This can also be done within one container with the use of pseudo classes, but I think this should give you a better idea how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sdvnksv